# Where is pyside-uic?

Tags: python, qt, pyside

I'm trying to use Qt Designer and pyside-uic mydesign.ui > design.py

however, this program doesn't exist. I looked in site packages under python 2.7, and I see:
pyside-lupdate.exe
pyside-rcc.exe

and a bunch of other programs, but there is no such thing as pyside-uic.exe  ... why ?? Why is it missing from the installation package? Where do I get it?

Comment: yeah, I read it but it didn't mean much to me. was hoping it would mean something to you, sorry if it didn't.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should see a /Python27/Scripts/pyside-uic.exe. But I'm wondering why it's not visible (not executable). Maybe it's a packaging problem (permissions, etc). You could try to call it using the complete path.

Comment: Thanks for finding it, I had searched but search couldn't find it. Now the problem is this: http://i.imgur.com/VOtRO.png

Comment: would the wrong architecture cause that? meaning: 64-bit executable on a 32-bit system or vice versa.

Comment: You're typing "python-uic", not "pyside-uic" on that screenshot.

Answer (score 9):

If you installed PySide with homebrew, you need to install `pyside-tools` package also to get these command line tools:

```
$ brew install pyside-tools
```

Answer (score 3):

When I installed using conda, the py-uic.exe was not unpacked. The problem was fixed by uninstalling and using pip.

```
>pip install pyside
```

Answer (score 2):

For Mac it worked for me running the following command (needed to have macports installed):

```
sudo port install py27-pyside-tools
```

It installs on my Python 2.7 environment. 
I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Since a couple years passed by and some things were fixed: I guess the official answer would now be:

Use **`uic.exe`**! But how?

So although [the official docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/uic.html) still lack any info about it you can now compile `.ui` files to Python directly with this executable shipped with the PySide2 package you get via `pip install PySide2`. This is how you would write it:

```
uic.exe -g python your_design.ui -o your_design_ui.py
```

Where `your_design.ui` is the Qt Designer file and `your_design_ui.py` the target Python file to generate. Voilà!

Btw: here is the help from `uic -?`

```
C:\Python38\Lib\site-packages\PySide2>uic.exe -h
Usage: uic.exe [options] [uifile]
Qt User Interface Compiler version 5.15.0

Options:
-?, -h, --help                Displays help on commandline options.
--help-all                    Displays help including Qt specific options.
-v, --version                 Displays version information.
-d, --dependencies            Display the dependencies.
-o, --output <file>           Place the output into <file>
-a, --no-autoconnection       Do not generate a call to
                                QObject::connectSlotsByName().
-p, --no-protection           Disable header protection.
-n, --no-implicit-includes    Disable generation of #include-directives.
-s, --no-stringliteral        Deprecated. The use of this option won't take
                                any effect.
--postfix <postfix>           Postfix to add to all generated classnames.
--tr, --translate <function>  Use <function> for i18n.
--include <include-file>      Add #include <include-file> to <file>.
-g, --generator <python|cpp>  Select generator.
--idbased                     Use id based function for i18n
--from-imports                Python: generate imports relative to '.'

Arguments:
[uifile]                      Input file (*.ui), otherwise stdin.
```

Answer (score 0):

In case someone need it, for Ubuntu 18.04 I need to install pyside-tools package first. Hope that helps.

```
sudo apt-get install pyside-tools
```

Comment: this does not work  `E: Unable to locate package pyside-tools`