# Where is PySide-uic.exe? (For Windows?)

Tags: python, qt, pyside, maya

I'm on the verge of giving up on trying to use PyQT4 in Maya 2016, already asked about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42107296/module-use-of-python34-dll-conflicts-with-this-version-of-python).

But, in a lot of places I've looked, I keep picking up the notion that I should be using PySide instead. And I would love to - but now I'm pretty much stuck trying to convert Qt Designer's .ui output via PySide uic.

I did took a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6684180/where-is-pyside-uic) - I even tried follow the accepted answer by typing in the full path, but for that I got:

```
"...pyside.uic.exe is not a recognized as an internal or external command, operable command or batch file."
```

the other suggestions in that post (like using sudo install) didn't work for me since im on Windows, not linux. And I couldn't comment there (wanting to ask how to do it on windows) since I don't have enough rep.

So the bottom line is I just would like to get a .ui file (from QT Designer) to open up in maya via a generated .py file.

Trying to do it via PyQt4 only lands me in a failure to load DLL error,
but trying to convert it to PySide is a problem because pyside-uic is not in my Python 27 scripts folder. I've been stuck here for a while now.

Anyone kind enough to offer some advice?

Thank you for your time.

Additional info:

```
I am using Maya 2016, running on a Windows 10 64 bit OS.
I have a Python 2.7 in my C: drive 
And I am now using PyQt4-4.10-gpl-Py2.7-Qt4.8.4-x64
I have a pyside and pysideuic folder inside Maya site packages folder
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need the exe.

does `from pysideuic import compileUi` work in your listener?

see : https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/maya/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2015/ENU/Maya/files/GUID-FAD0F6CC-15D0-4489-9372-028146B70F49-htm.html

Comment: I've tried that before posting the question. I just keep getting: # Error: line 1: IOError: file <maya console> line 9: 22 #

Comment: Did you run the script from a mayapy commandline instance, like the link wants?

Comment: hi - thanks for your responses - and your patience. Unfortunately I'm in a spot where I didn't ask to be in - I'm completely unqualified in all this - but still just trying to learn what i can from scattered pieces of information online.

that said - I have no idea what a mayapy commandline instance is - googling on it led me to a couple of blogs that just took me to a deeper direction that i cant comprehend. One of the blogs led me to discover a maya py. exe file in the bin folder - but when i try to run the example there - im getting an invalid module error

Comment: so yeah sorry for being difficult - I'm still doing searches but - i get stuck at places where i dont undertand the information, like here for example: http://www.bewi.at/?p=245 - now im thinking if i should install pyside-tools? (since i found a pyside-uic file, not a .exe inside my maya bin folder)

Comment: so `cd  "C:\program files\autodesk\maya2016\bin"` followed by `mayapy pyside-uic <path-to-your-ui-file>` does not work?  It should print out what looks like a python file.  You'd then pipe that into a new .py file

Comment: http://i990.photobucket.com/albums/af24/Themimegogo/ForumUse/1.jpg Nope didn't work.

Comment: the cd and the mayapy.. etc should be on separate lines.  The first is to get you into the maya bin directory; the second calls mayapy (which lives in bin) on the pyside-uic file (which also lives there).  You can navigate there with explorer and use 'command window here' to avoid the CD

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't even bother trying to convert the `ui` files to python files.  You can just load the `ui` files dynamically.  In `PyQt4`, they had a function that would do this for you -- `PyQt4.uic.loadUi`.  Pyside doesn't have that exact same function, but it has similar tools, and [people have created a function that does essentially the same thing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14892713/1547004).

Also, you shouldn't be using your own installed `PyQt4`.  Maya compiles their own version of `Qt`, which may not be compatible with your `PyQt` binaries.  They provide their own compiled `PySide` binaries with Maya, so just use those.

Comment: thanks for the response. I've already uninstalled pyQT4 - but right now the situation is - prior to doing anything - I kept getting the "no module named PyQt4" error. After I installed PyQt4 and copied it into the Lib Site packages folder in Maya - then I got it working at least (was that bad? because i have no idea how i was supposed to get it running in the first place). Anyway - I'm being instructed to convert it to .py but I just cant use psyideuic in the same way I just used pyuic4 in the command prompt.

Comment: You're getting the no module named PyQt4 error because PyQt4 isn't installed in the maya python.  Don't use PyQt4; don't copy it manually.  Maya comes with PySide, use that. If you *must* convert it to .py files, inside the PySide folder there should be a `uic.py` script `/PySide/scripts/uic.py`.  You should be able to use that the same way you did pyuic

Comment: http://i990.photobucket.com/albums/af24/Themimegogo/ForumUse/noPySideScripts.jpg Nope sorry - I looked at both Pyside and pysideuic folders inside my Maya location - as you can see - nothing there. Afterwards I tried to search for a uic.py - and my machine pointed me to a winexe folder left behind by the previous user of my machine - but it was named uic.pyo - I also checked the machines of two colleagues, they didnt have a scripts folder in PySide folders as well

Comment: Hmm, odd.  Try downloading and installing PySide to your system python (make sure it's 2.7, same as Maya).  It should have that script